# Django: Read only field

Tags: django, django-admin, customization

How do I allow fields to be populated by the user at the time of object creation ("add" page) and then made read-only when accessed at "change" page?

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution I found was to override the get_readonly_fields function of ModelAdmin:

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        '''
        Override to make certain fields readonly if this is a change request
        '''
        if obj is not None:
            return self.readonly_fields + ('title',)
        return self.readonly_fields
admin.site.register(TestModel, TestAdmin)
```

Object will be none for the add page, and an instance of your model for the change page.
Edit: Please note this was tested on Django==1.2

Comment: wow i was about to edit the model template, thanks , this worked great :)

Answer (score 3):

There's two thing to address in your question.

#### 1. Read-only form fields

Doesn't exist as is in Django, but you can implement it yourself, and [this blog post](http://lazypython.blogspot.com/2008/12/building-read-only-field-in-django.html) can help.

#### 2. Different form for add/change

I guess you're looking for a solution in the admin site context (otherwise, just use 2 different forms in your views).

You could eventually override `add_view` or `change_view` in your `ModelAdmin` and use a different form in one of the view, but I'm afraid you will end up with an awful load of duplicated code.

Another solution I can think of, is a form that will modify its fields upon instantiation, when passed an `instance` parameter (ie: an *edit* case). Assuming you have a `ReadOnlyField` class, that would give you something like:

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stuff

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('instance') is not None:
            self.fields['title'] = ReadOnlyField()
```

In here, the field `title` in the model `Stuff` will be read-only on the change page of the admin site, but editable on the creation form.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit that model's save method to handle such a requirement. For example, you can check if the field already contains some value, if it does, ignore the new value.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to [override or replace](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) the change_form template for that specific model.

Comment: note that changing only the template is *not* secure. An user can still submit the field in a forged _POST_ that will get accepted on the server-side.